# Origini ed etimologia della particella 'nee' alla fine di frasi in dialetti del Nord Italia

Tags: grammar, etymology, regional

Soprattutto nel nord-ovest sento spesso usare 'nee' alla fine di talune asserzioni, per esempio:

> - 'Non chiederlo ancora, nee.'
> - 'Prendi il libro, nee.'
> - 'Sono stanco ora, nee.'

Sapreste dirmi precisamente cosa significhi e quali siano le origini storiche di questo 'nee'? E' per caso un francesismo?

Comment: This is typical of some parts of Lombardy. I wouldn't consider it Italian.

Comment: I am not familiar with it (I live in Rome). What does it mean?

Comment: @DaG, I dunno, too.

Comment: è chiaramente derivato dal giapponese: anche in giapponese si usa quel "nè" nello stesso modo e negli stessi sensi."
- - - - OK, OK; che "anche in giapponese si usi quel "nè" nello stesso modo e negli stessi sensi." è verissimo e potete constatarlo facilmente chiedendo a qualunque giapponese; per quanto riguarda l'etimologia, e cioè per quanto riguarda la frase <<è chiaramente derivato dal giapponese>>, stavo scherzando, ragazzi, scusate :-) Dai, su, ora che ho chiarito questo, il mio intervento è utile, o almeno, interessante, no? Allora potreste darmi un voto positivo, nè?!

Comment: Spiacente, ma non mi pare di trovare né utilità né interesse in questa risposta, che può al massimo essere un commento: “È, se non altro, curioso che la stessa sillaba sia usata in giapponese allo stesso modo”.

Comment: In portoghese si dice, per confermare la frase precedente: não é? I brasiliani dicono: né, immagino come contrazione di não é.

Answer (score 11):

***Nee*** è un intercalare usato in alcuni dialetti del Nord Italia.

In dialetti come il Piemontese la *e* finale è particolarmente allungata e da qui la grafia *nee*. In altri dialetti della Lombardia (come ad esempio il Milanese) il suono è invece più secco, con una *e* corta, ed è solitamente scritto come *neh* o *né*.

Si usa esclusivamente a fine della frase al fine di rafforzarne il significato e richiedere una sorta di conferma da parte dell'ascoltatore.

Circa la sua origine, penso derivi semplicemente dalla parola ***eh***, usata con significato identico (francamente ignoro se questo utilizzo sia dialettale o meno).
Sospetto che l'aggiunta della *n* sia dovuta a motivi fonetici, in modo da legare meglio la frase quando ***eh*** è preceduto da una parola che termina con una vocale.

In Italiano può essere facilmente tradotto con espressioni del tipo *mi raccomando* o *capito?*, in dipendenza dal contesto, ad esempio

> Non chiederlo ancora, mi raccomando! 
>   Prendi il libro, capito?

Comment: _Nee_ per me è più piemontese che lombardo. Come lombardo, userei _neh_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno giusta precisazione. Mi ero scordato del piemontese :)

Comment: Al Nord-Est userei una bestemmia :D

Answer (score 10):

It might be borrowed from the French, the expression "***n'est-ce pas?***" has a similar use and meaning.

> "*n'est-ce pas?*" (pronunciation /nɛsˈpa/) → "***neé?***" (nɛˈ).

---

*Please note that this is only my opinion, I have no references to back up my claim.*

Comment: This feels like the correct answer to the question

Comment: If you look at an answer below that is backed up by the Treccani dictionary, the very same origin of né is pointed out, except that it uses the italian translation of your sentence as the source. 

Consider the fact that Lombard and Piedmontese (and several others) are gallo-romance languages, and as such have similarities to French. Maybe it came from there. 

Who knows where it comes from exactly. What is clear is that it means the same thing as "nevvero", this should clarify things for who asked the answer.

Answer (score 9):

La risposta a questa domanda è abbastanza ovvia: "neh" significa "n(on) è (vero?)".

[Si tratta](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/neh/) di una «esclamazione interrogativa, di carattere enfatico: si usa specialmente in Piemonte e in Lombardia, in fine di frase o parenteticamente, quasi a chiedere conferma di ciò che si dice, o per richiamare comunque l’attenzione».

È simile a ["nevvero"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/nevvero/)

In Italiano ["ve'"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ve/) è invece il troncamento di "vedi!".

Comment: I don't know in the rest of Italy, but in Rome _ve'_ stands for _vero_ ("ieri sera hai fatto tardi, ve'?")

Comment: I couldn't find any source confirming that, but I totally agree that in Romanesco "ve'?" is the apocope of "vero?" (or perhaps "nevvero?"?).

Comment: This answer is the most straightforward one, and it's the only answer backed by an official source!

Answer (score 6):

It's just an expression, a "way to say". It could easily be compared to

> 'Don't ask it again, ***ok***?' 
>   'Take the book, ***ok***?.' 
>   'I am tired, ***ok***?.'

It's like a rhetorical question, to get that particular person's attention. I use it always and I live in Lombardia near Milan.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine a positive sentence in English like "This is your phone, ***isn't it***?" and a question like "Tomorrow we'll go to the cinema, ***OK***?". In some regional use of the north west Italy, to render the parts I wrote bold you use the particle "neh" or "ne'" (also based on different way to pronounce that in different areas). In particular in Piedmont, mostly in Turin and Biella counties people speaking strict dialect use "ne'".
Other regional dialects in Italy do something similar with different particles. For example in Emilia Romagna's counties of Reggio, Modena and Bologna, some similar use is made by ending sentences with "ve'" or "veh".
But considering that correct Italian comes from vulgar Latin, through Tuscan dialect, those regional dialectical (even if common) uses are just not Italian language.

Alex

Answer (score 3):

I am from Piedmont. Typical Piedmontese sentences may be:

Atënsion! Ël ciòt a l'è ancreus, neh! = Warning! The hole is *really* deep!

Sera la porta, neh! = *Come on*, close the door!

Apress la cà a jè 'n giardin, neh? = Behind the house there is a garden, isn't there?

Notice in the latter a certain similarity with the German **nicht wahr** and the Dutch **nietwaar**

Heute hast Du das Haus gekauft, nicht wahr? = Today you have bought the house, haven't you?

Wij moeten nog een paar dingen zeggen, nietwaar? = We still have to say a couple of things, don't we?

Comment: Or in several German dialekts: Heut haste's Haus gekauft, **ne**?

Answer (score 0):

Credo che provenga dalla particella "ne" latina, la quale si poneva in modo enfatico in aggiunta ad una parola di una domanda quando essa richiedeva una risposta con no o sì (negativa o affermativa), ad
esempio:

nonne vis ire? = non vuoi andare?

vivus estne? = è vivo?

Ciò non esclude quindi che in una varietà nordica del latino il ne venisse messo sempre in fine frase.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE! Hai qualche riferimento per questa interpretazione? La risposta sarebbe interessante se ci fossero degli esempi nella letteratura che suggeriscono questa transizione.

Answer (score -2):

La soluzione è molto più semplice: deriva dal latino

> non est.

In piemonte sono diffuse le varianti *neh* e *né*.

Si dice per confermare la frase precedente:

> döman as vedduma neh (domani ci vediamo neh).

Comment: paolo, l'origine latina è una tua ipotesi o hai qualche fonte?