# "Question tag" /nɛ/: n'è, neh o nè?

Tags: etymology, orthography, regional

Nell'Italiano parlato (perlomeno in Brianza e a Milano) si usa spesso la "parola" /nɛ/ per fare una "question tag", quello che in Inglese si fa ripetendo il verbo al negativo e mettendo un pronome soggetto. Chi lo usa nello scritto (tipicamente sui social) lo scrive tipicamente "neh". Io ho pensato che potrebbe avere origine da "no è" = "non è [vero/così]", e quindi andrebbe scritto "n'è". C'è qualche fonte più autorevole che abbia questa opinione? Meglio "neh", "n'è" o (altra forma più rara) "nè/né"?

Comment: Potresti fare un esempio in inglese?

Comment: @Charo "You're going, aren't you?", ovvero "Tu vai, n'è?".

Comment: È un uso regionale, che associo al Nord-Ovest d'italia (ma non sono sicuro al 100% che sia localizzato solo lì). Ti posso assicurare che se provi ad usarlo in Veneto riceverai degli sguardi molto perplessi...

Comment: Eh beh @Denis io sono brianzolo :).

Comment: Dovresti correggere la tua domanda, perché "nel parlato italiano" (tout court) è sbagliato

Comment: Nel profondo sud di Roma non è arrivato.

Comment: Se ne parlava anche in [un'altra domanda](http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1369/origini-ed-etimologia-della-particella-nee-alla-fine-di-frasi-in-dialetti-del), ma non mi sembra che ci fosse una risposta risolutiva. La risposta più convincente si richiama al [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/neh/), che avalla l'ipotesi “n(on) è”. Non vedo però perché scriverlo “n'è”, che significherebbe “ne è” (come in “è finito, non ce n'è più”).

Comment: Mi piace vederlo come contrazione di *nevvero*... e per quanto alla scrittura, meglio non scriverlo, a parte che non si stia scrivendo una commedia in dialetto lombardo (nel qual caso userei *ne'*).

Comment: Se ti va di vedere come lo interpretano degli autori trovi materiale [qui](http://www.attoripercaso.it/copioni-commediedialettali.htm). Menichetti in *... E chi viv se la spassa!* usa *nèh*.

Comment: @DaG n'è come "no è". In Dante si trova "no" per "non". Quindi n' vorrebbe essere elisione di "no" per "non", in "n'è" a fine frase, e non di "ne". Certo, l'ambiguità c'è, ma a fine frase "ne è" non ce lo vedo molto :).

Comment: @MickG: Siamo d'accordo, dal contesto è chiaro che qui con “n'è” non intendi “ne è”, ma visto che nei dizionari e presso gli autori dialettali è attestata la grafia “neh”, non mi è chiaro perché usarne una diversa che per giunta ha già un altro significato.

Comment: @DaG Voleva solo essere una grafia "etimologica", ma se "neh" è usata anche dagli autori credo che la adotterò anch'io.

Comment: Proporrei di sostituire il termine "italiano parlato" con "lombardo italianizzato" o anche "lombardo occidentale italianizzato". Nel resto d'Italia non si usa il "/nɛ/: n'è, neh o nè"

Comment: In Brasile è molto usata la parola "né?" che è la contrazione di "não é?", con il significato di "non è vero?" o, in francese, "n'est pas?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La particella *ne* è presente molto simile in varie lingue di Paesi vicini (in portoghese come contrazione di *não é*, in tedesco *nö* o *neh* al posto di *nein?*); se provenisse dal francese (come corruzione di *n'est-ce pas?*), questo potrebbe spiegare perché sia diffusa nel nord Italia, ma non al centro o al sud, e specialmente nella zona di Milano, visto che il dialetto meneghino [mutua molti termini dal francese](http://www.tesionline.it/consult/brano.jsp?id=13492).

Esiste la forma "n'è" per "non è", la usava anche il Manzoni, ma è rara ([*Ne abbiam passate di brutte, n'è vero, miei giovani?*](http://promessisposi.weebly.com/capitolo-xxxviii.html)) e per quanto riesco a trovare, è sempre usata nella forma "n'è vero". Può darsi che "neh" derivi da una contrazione di *non è vero?*, ma in tal caso andrebbe probabilmente scritta "ne'", come forma elisa di *nevvero*.

Soprattutto, nel rileggere "n'è", almeno io interpreterei come "ne è".

Perciò, tutto sommato, io lascerei indicato *neh*.

Comment: Che c'entra il giapponese?

Comment: Più che di “n'è” usato per “non è”, parlerei, per quell'esempio, di diverse grafie della parola/locuzione “nevvero” (cf. http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/nevvero/).

Comment: Giusto, ho corretto la risposta. Per quanto riguarda il riferimento al giapponese, è che mi stavo baloccando con l'idea balzana che il suono N terminale potesse nascere da qualcosa tipo l'effetto *kiki-bouba*.

Comment: Interessante ipotesi, ma questa sorta di congetture sugli universali del linguaggio va sempre affrontata con infinita cautela, visto che persino le onomatopee differiscono grandemente da lingua a lingua. E poi, personalmente, avrei qualche perplessità su una teoria che trovasse affinità tra un tratto dell'italiano di certe regioni settentrionali e il giapponese, quando questo tratto non è condiviso neppure dall'italiano di altre regioni.

Comment: Giusto. Avevo detto che era una idea balzana. Magari tolgo il riferimento, che in effetti può lasciare perplessi...

Comment: Tornando in tema, mi sembra interessante l'idea di usare la grafia “ne'” (anche per affinità con po', be', to'...), ma probabilmente arriviamo un po' tardi per introdurla adesso.

Comment: @DaG Però tutti gli esempi che hai fatto sono elisioni (_poco_, _bene_, _togli_), mentre non è affatto chiaro se _neh_ sia l'elisione di qualcosa (anche se lo fosse di _nevvero_, questa parola a sua volta viene da _non è vero_, quindi _neh_ sarebbe soltanto _non è_, e dunque nessuna vera elisione).